# WSO2DSS nested query with JSON response

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Using WSO2DSS 3.5.1 we have nested query returnning pagination information and a sub-list of items.

For XML it looks all simple:

```
    <result element="results" rowName="result" >
        <element column="pagecount"   name="pageCount"   xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="resultcount" name="resultCount" xsdType="integer"/>
        <element column="currpage"    name="page"        xsdType="integer"/>
        <call-query href="positions_list">
            <with-param name="page" query-param="page"/>
        </call-query>
    </result>
```

**How could we use nested queries (query-call) with JSON response?** When requesting "Accept: application/json" header, we receive StackOverflow error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.xml.namespace.QName.equals(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.getNode(HashMap.java:571)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaObjectTable.getItem(XmlSchemaObjectTable.java:50)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.getTypeByName(XmlSchema.java:296)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema.getTypeByName(XmlSchema.java:346)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.getSchemaTypeOfElement(XmlNodeGenerator.java:146)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.processElement(XmlNodeGenerator.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.processSchemaType(XmlNodeGenerator.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.processElement(XmlNodeGenerator.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.processSchemaType(XmlNodeGenerator.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.json.gson.factory.XmlNodeGenerator.processElement(XmlNodeGenerator.java:137)
```

so far we identified it happend when requesting JSON response with nested queries.

To return JSON response looks simple (and pretty straightforward to convert to XML)

```
    <result outputType="json">
      {"UserPositionListPage": {
        { "pageCount": $pagecount,
          "resultCount": $resultcount,
          "page": $currpage       
        }   }          
    </result>
```

However we see no way to include response from an nested call. Any advice / idea?

Edit: seems I have to work on repeatable case as we already have a service returning XML with nested calls and it works ever when requesting json :/ I wouldn't mind if the service would always return JSON or XML regardless requested content type (assuming we could use ESB or APIM for transformation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating axis2.xml to use message formatter and builder from the *org.apache.axis2.json* package (instead of "gson") at least solved the StackOverflowError

```
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                      class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>

    <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                    class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>
```

so basically using different (older?) json formatter and builder allow us returning the XML with nested queries and let the  DSS convert the response

EDIT:

Nested JSON queries are described in the DOC: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Exposing+Data+in+JSON+Format#ExposingDatainJSONFormat-NestedQueries

```
{
  "result": {
  "total": $total,
  "limit": $page_limit,
  "offset": $page_offset,
  "@positions_list": "$limit->limit,$offset->offset"
       }
}
```

calling the positions_list query as a nested query